# How to use resnet by reading the .ckpt file of my learned weights with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, load, visualization, resnet

In pytorch, how can I write the code that loads my .ckpt file instead of

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
```

Here is my attempt below

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)

PATH = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mlearning2/multi_logs/resnet_2/version_0/checkpoints/epoch=1-step=2543.ckpt"

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

But it could not work and the following error appeared.

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.weight", "bn1.weight", "bn1.bias", "bn1.running_mean", "bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.bias", "layer1.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.bias", "layer1.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn2.running_var", "layer1.0.conv3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.bias", "layer1.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn3.running_var", "layer1.0.downsample.0.weight", "layer1.0.downsample.1.weight", "layer1.0.downsample.1.bias", "layer1.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "layer1.0.downsample.1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.bias", "layer1.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.bias", "layer1.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn2.running_var", "layer1.1.conv3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.bias", "layer1.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn3.running_var", "layer1.2.conv1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.bias", "layer1.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn1.running_var", "layer1.2.conv2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.bias", "layer1.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn2.running_var", "layer1.2.conv3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.bias", "layer1.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn3.running_var", "layer2.0.conv1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.bias", "layer2.0.bn1...
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "epoch", "global_step", "pytorch-lightning_version", "state_dict", "callbacks", "optimizer_states", "lr_schedulers", "hparams_name", "hyper_parameters".
```

How can I do it?

@Shai I tried to run

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))['state_dict'])
```

however got the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your saved checkpoint contains not only a snapshot of the trained weights of the model but some other useful information on the state of the training (e.g., the state of the optimizer etc.).

Try selecting only the relevant part of the saved checkpoint:

```py
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))['state_dict'])
```

---

**Update**
Based on the modification you made and the new error you received, it seems like the model that was saved is `model.backbone = torchvision.models.resnet50()`.

You need to instantiate your `model` in the same manner as done during training.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried it but still have error. I edited the question and put the error there

Comment: Thank u for your reply. My understanding is not that clear yet. What can I attempt to do next then?